# Can I with PTEs from one process which indicate to fragments of physical memory to create appropriate PTEs in other process?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, posix

When we in Linux use function `mmap (,,, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED);`, then for the same region of fragmented physically memory (which allocated) between processes are allocating virtual memory pages (PTEs). Ie these PTEs are copied from page table of one process to the page table of another process (with the same sequence of fragments of physical addresses allocated memory), is this true?

But `mmap ()` needs to be done before `fork ()`. And if we already have two working process (ie after `fork ()`), then we need to use a **file** for the `mmap()`. Which functions used to copying mechanism of PTEs between the two already established processes to create a shared memory?

Can I with PTEs/SGL(scatter-gather-list) which indicate to fragments of physical memory which have been allocated to create appropriate PTEs in other process by using linux-kernel, and how to do it?

I want to understand how it `mmap()` works at a lower level .

Answer (score 1):

> When we in Linux use function `mmap (,,, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED);`, then
> for the same region of fragmented physically memory (which allocated)
> between processes are allocating virtual memory pages (PTEs).

Restate the question/statement, please, the above does not make sense.

> Ie these PTEs are copied from page table of one process to the page
> table of another process (with the same sequence of fragments of
> physical addresses allocated memory), is this true?

No, it is not true.

When you establish a new mapping, a kernel first looks
for a sufficiently large unused range of addresses in the virtual address space of the process. Then it modifies the corresponding page table entries to indicate that that address range is valid, but physical pages there are not present.

When you attempt to access an address in that range, a page fault is generated. The kernel looks in its data structures and determines that the access is valid. Then it allocates a
fresh physical page, modifies the page entry to establish the mapping between the
virtual address and the physical address and marks the page as present. Upon return from
the page fault exception, the offending instruction is restarted and this time executes successfully.

> But mmap () needs to be done before fork (). And if we already have
> two working process (ie after fork ()), then we need to use a file for
> the mmap(). Which functions used to copying mechanism of PTEs between
> the two already established processes to create a shared memory?

If you do a `mmap` after the `fork`, the two processes will create and initialize
page table entries entirely independent of each other. However, when you `mmap` a file,
the kernel will not allocate simply a free physical page - it will allocate a page,
fill it with data from the file and put the page in the page/buffer cache. When a second
process mmaps the same file, the kernel looks in the page cache, finds there the physical
page, which corresponds to the same file and the required file offset and points the PTE
to that page. Now, there will be two completely independently created PTE, which just point to the same physical page.

> Can I with PTEs/SGL(scatter-gather-list) which indicate to fragments
> of physical memory which have been allocated to create appropriate
> PTEs in other process by using linux-kernel, and how to do it?

Restate this too, it's not clear what you are asking.

> I want to understand how it mmap() works at a lower level .

I would recommend an operating systems book, a chapter on virtual memory management,
something like [Operating System Concepts by Silberschatz el al.](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Operating-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/1118112733/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1386065707&sr=8-5&keywords=Operating%20System%20Concepts,%20by%20Silberschatz,%20Galvin,%20and%20Gagne)

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Operating-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/1118112733/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1386065707&sr=8-5&keywords=Operating+System+Concepts%2C+by+Silberschatz%2C+Galvin%2C+and+Gagne