# Where is linux shared memory actually located?

Tags: c, linux, memory, shared-memory

I just wanted to know where shared memory resides in a Linux system? Is it in physical memory or virtual memory?

I am aware about the process's virtual memory send boxes, they are different from process to process and processes don't see each other's memory, but we can pass the data between processes using IPC. To implement the simple scenario I have just created a simple shared memory program and try to print the shared memory address and value returned from `shmat` function, however, the processes have different addresses but same values.

Here is the write program.

**write.c**

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  key_t key=1235;
  int shm_id;
  void *shm;

  int *ptr = 83838;

  shm_id = shmget(key,10,IPC_CREAT | 0666);
  shm = shmat(shm_id,NULL,NULL);

  sprintf(shm,"%d",ptr);

  printf("Address is %p, Value is %p \n", (void *)shm, (void *)&ptr);
  printf("Shm value is %d \n", *(int *)shm);
  return;
}
```

Here is the reader program.

**read.c**

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  key_t key=1235;
  int shm_id;
  void *shm;

  int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  shm_id = shmget(key,10,NULL);
  shm = shmat(shm_id,NULL,NULL);
  if(shm == NULL)
  {
    printf("error");
  }
  sscanf(shm,"%d",p);
  printf("Address is %p %p %p %d\n",(void *)shm, (void *)p, (void *)&p, *p);
  printf("Shared value is %d \n", *(int *)shm);
  return 0;
}
```

It would be great if someone could please explain in detail how the processes see the same value despite having different addresses?

This question comes from [C pass void pointer using shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279725/c-pass-void-pointer-using-shared-memory).

Comment: their real physical addresses are shared

Comment: As you've understood the explanation given in the answer, please accept it

Answer (score 33):

All memory that is committed is physical.

However processes cannot address physical memory directly. They have virtual addresses which the kernel will resolve to physical addresses. When a shared memory region is setup, the same physical memory location is addressed by the multiple processes. However the virtual addresses can be different though. Each process uses the virtual address it received only in its own context. Both the virtual addresses refer to the same physical memory.

---

To elaborate, in case of a shared memory region, the same physical memory address is addressable by multiple processes simultaneously as both the processes have virtual addresses that point to the same physical address.

For example consider the following :

- virtual address **V1** ( in process **T1** context)
- virtual address **V2** ( in process **T2** context)

are both pointing to the shared memory region.
This is actually a common physical address **P**.

Now,
Process **T1** referencing virtual address **V1**
*OR*
Process **T2** referencing virtual address **V2**

will result in an access to physical address **P** as the kernel translates both the virtual address locations to the same physical location in memory.

---

For example, in the following diagram, the physical memory **PFN4** is shared by processes X and Y using **VPFN3** and **VPFN1** in their respective contexts (PFN stands for Page Frame Number).

[image: Virtual memory maps for 2 processes]

Comment: OK. Got it. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Now clear. But In the link shared by me in that I was trying to share a process address using shared memory and in second example I was trying to read the address and value on that address, but I can only either  share address or value, not both.

Comment: A virtual address is valid only in it process context. Once a context-switch occurs and a different process is running, the new page tables loaded may not contain a physical location mapping for that particular address causing a segfault. Even if con-incidentally a physical memory location is indeed mapped to the same virtual address in the new process, it is NOT guaranteed to point to the same physical memory location as in the original process. Go through this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20348391/319204) to properly understand the problem you are facing.